# Does the community acknowledge potential harm to mental health by excessive usage of math stackexchange

Tags: discussion, community

I am not sure whether this is an appropriate question. Perhaps it will be closed, or perhaps not.

It is generally the case that people derive satisfaction from getting their responses validated on Q and A sites such as StackExchange. It is not far fetched to presume that a someone may get too invested in this satisfaction, and this may create an imbalance in their real life. An addiction to getting upvotes and acceptance from others is not a healthy state of affairs and may affect a person's mental health. Young people, who are not having many outside interests (which probably is the case with several students starting their mathematical studies) are particularly vulnerable.

It is of course not the business of math.stackexchange to make judgements in this regard even in general, but is there a formal acknowledgment of the above phenomena by the community? Afterall, this is a community of well meaning human beings!

To give some context, let me post the highest voted answer to a question posted previously on meta: [Why do *you* answer questions on math.stackexchange?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/why-do-you-answer-questions-on-math-stackexchange)

> I am needy and insecure and derive validation from the gratitude of strangers.

Comment: Most people who cling to math already, may have social conflicts in reality. So they get put down. So you can argue for balancing some of the effects.

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26466/42969, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31051/42969

Comment: @Shahab  Framing of a question has everything to do with what answers one obtains.  Compare the link from MartinR above, and your link, with my early early early question years ago:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/what-do-you-really-like-about-working-with-contributing-to-math-se?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Asking with the sense that there is a danger/problems/additions generally generates confirming input.  Asking the same question, when focusing on gains, rewards, fulfillment, generates it's own confirming input.  I'll suggest your very title and body of your question suggests you're inclined to think it may be problematic, or you've experienced imbalance in your own life, and you are looking for others to pretty much confirm, or challenge that belief.

Comment: I'll also note that the answer you quote was an *inside joke*: earlier on, we often joked about "addiction" to the site, but it can be a problem for some users, even many users at some point.  So your concern is valid, just leave room for wondering if the comment you quoted was meant to be a joke, given the subsequent comments.

Comment: @amWhy Personally I am not a very regular user of the site, I just happened to read about a user today with a very high reputation on math StackExchange and math overflow who quit graduate school. This triggered this question probably.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  Many high rep users are retired, and likely looking for ways to have an impact.  But you do raise a good point, and yes, that has happened to at least three users here and on MO, what you speak of, who were in PhD programs.  But comparing Academia to math.se is a stretch, though while pursuing one's PhD, creating a productive balance is crucial.  The same holds true for students at all level, and professors... creating balance is huge and ultimately required for ones success/happiness, etc., etc.

Comment: @amWhy What you say is, I think, the position of almost everyone who is experienced in life. The issue is that practically this topic of living a balanced life is not brought up on Q & A sites such as ours because it is deemed off-topic. But users may get addicted to validation from here and particularly young people may suffer consequences when real life catches up with them. IMHO the topic ought to be at least formally acknowledged in some way. I am not sure what is the appropriate way to do that, or even whether it is being done already.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Some users have recognized such a pull to spend time here, when younger.  Some recognized they need to spend less time (say, when summer changes to the fall semester).  Of these, some fine they have to, and force a limit on themselves, others find they are missing sleep trying to keep up with coursework and with math.se.  We've had users ask to be suspended from this site, until, say, the end of a semester. Mod's will assist them in that request.

Comment: But I do think more could be done, in this respect.  What doesn't help at all is the "gaming" aspects of this network, and others too.  I see it play out, even among some of the retired folks, who limit sleep to be hear 18-20 hours a day.  It's actually sad, very sad, but one or a few of them seeks to be the top in everything: rep for the month/year...number of overall reviews...

Comment: This is quite shocking. You say that 'more could be done, in this respect'; do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is [a post concerning my struggle](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32972/316409) and how I got over it. It actually addresses two struggles in equal parts : MSE addiction, but also the addiction to answering poor quality questions as well (which can happen even if one isn't often on MSE). I've cut my MSE time by more than $70$% since writing that post , but made it about twice or three times more productive with some efforts I describe in that answer. I hope everybody can use this site well, but I can't write an answer to this question which is better than what I wrote there!

Comment: Excessive use of any online platform is a problem. What is the purpose of making various entities own parts of that problem?

Comment: I am not sure whether lumping together all online platforms is appropriate. Math SE is different from say Facebook and has its own peculiarities. We ought to acknowledge (in some way) the problems caused by its excessive usage.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon. Thank you for sharing your struggle. Perhaps there should be a standing community wiki post on meta where users can share their experiences with mental peace problems related to Math SE. That would be one way of acknowledging this phenomena.

Comment: @Shahab I think that particular step is in the right direction, but you've actually exposed the elephant in the room: that itself is great service. SE (and a lot of "addictive" websites) by itself does nothing in its mechanisms to discourage excessive participation, apart from a reputation cap whose effectiveness I cannot vouch for. I would endorse your idea of having such a meta page for documenting these , possibly as anonymous entries.

Comment: All things in moderation.

Comment: I somehow have 208 days consecutive on this site and counting,

Comment: This is an issue in facebook and all social media, isn't it?

Comment: @Shahab I don’t see anything constructive in pleading a special case that excessive use of math.se is somehow tangibly different than excessive use of any site.  The solutions would be the same.

Comment: You know, people can get addicted to math too. Maybe the math community should acknowledge that math is potentially harmful to mental health...

Comment: Addiction to math.stackexchange is much, much better than addiction to Twitter.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this topic up. I understand badges and points are not "bad" by itself, but I find this system based on rewards potentially addictive and dangerous. We as a society should talk more about this and be aware of how harmful social media (even a well meaning community like MSE) in general can be.

Comment: @Shahab I like your idea of a CW post for discussing possible effects of participation in Maths.SE on mental health. In response to a comment by rschwieb: this needn't be to single out Maths.SE as especially problematic, because it's a meta issue that arises for any online forum, and arguably is worth addressing explicitly. (But it could be very difficult to do so.) I think it's worth adding that "excessive use" isn't the only possible problem. For example, I have been a member for well over 6 years, and have only visited on 751 days, but I suffered severe stress because of Maths.SE last year.

Comment: Being exceptional in any field requires a great deal of obsession unless you are extremely lucky or talented.

Comment: It’s almost like we are all obsessed with this (+25) post which itself is about being obsessed.

Comment: excessive comments

Comment: @Shahab After some checking of SE blogs and meta.stackexchange posts, there have been discussions around addiction , mental health , and the SE model's encouragement of addiction. But that doesn't count to me as something "official" (although if it does address your question, maybe I will try to take a look at it). I don't think there has been "staff" participation on any of these meta posts either. In conclusion, there isn't any official acknowledgement, but without doubt there has been a community acknowledgement of this, at least going by 5-10 posts on meta SE.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon : that's interesting to know. Maybe you can post links to those discussions here as an answer to this post.

Comment: If my kid ever tells me he's addicted answering questions on math.stackexchange, I will take immediate action, namely, bring the entire family out to celebrate.

Comment: @Gavin What do you mean by celebrate?

Comment: Related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/how-to-recover-from-tex-se-or-in-general-tex-latex-addiction/7217#7217